# Como criar um .exe que não precisa executar como administrador?

Tags: c#, permissões, .exe

Eu fiz um script de um trainer pro FIFA15, é mais algo pra ajudar a comunidade, agora estou gerando uma versão pra todo mundo conseguir rodar. Segue o código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace cheat_birthyear
{
class Program
{
    public static string path;
    public static IntPtr BaseAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("fifa15");
        if(processes.Length > 0)
        {
            IntPtr BaseAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
            Process MyProc = processes[0];
            foreach(ProcessModule module in MyProc.Modules)
            {
                if (module.ModuleName.Contains("fifa15"))
                {
                    BaseAddress = module.BaseAddress;
                    path = module.FileName;
                    Console.WriteLine(path);

                }
            }

            if (BaseAddress != IntPtr.Zero)
            {


                VAMemory memory = new VAMemory("fifa15");
                long finalAddress = memory.ReadInt64((IntPtr)BaseAddress + 0x01F441E8);
                int newaddr = memory.ReadInt32( (IntPtr)finalAddress + 0x390);

                string yearPath = path.Replace("fifa15.exe", "cheat_birthyear\\birthyear.txt");
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@yearPath);
                string yearVal = lines[0];

                memory.WriteInt32( (IntPtr)finalAddress + 0x390, Int32.Parse(yearVal) );

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("baseaddress não encontrado");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("jogo não encontrado");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

E essas são as configurações pra gerar a versão de publicação:
[image: print]

Só estou tendo um problema agora, quando alguém abre o .exe sem dar as permissões de administrador, acontece o seguinte erro:
[image: print2]

Mas quando a pessoa executa o .exe clicando com botão direito e executar como administrador, tudo funciona perfeitamente, então minha dúvida é: Como posso criar esse executável para que ele rode sem essas permissões?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

No arquivo manifesto da aplicação deve colocar:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Nada garante que não pedirá privilégio de administrador porque depende de quem chamará o seu executável.

Porém pode ser que sua aplicação não rode corretamente, ou nem rode. Aí a única solução é não usar recursos que exigem privilégio de administrador para funcionar. Você não espera acessar os processos da máquina e modificar um executável na memória sem privilégio de administrador, né?

Comment: Vc tem razão kkk, eu fiz isso, mas ainda tenho um "problema", pq meu cheat precisa rodar somente dps q o jogo ja estiver aberto, o que eu fiz foi um .bat que inicia o jogo e 5s dps inicia o cheat, ai ele abre a janelinha de confirmação, mas nesse caso o jogo ja foi aberto e a janelinha não fica visível pro usuário.